# Can I use question mark in ALTER query?

Tags: javascript, sql, html, web-sql, alter

I tried to create a table and then add a bunch of new columns into it. It was implemented by Javascript (the database used is SQLite in websql I think):

```
var FFFNames = ["DEFAULTY", "LAGACY", "MATADATA"];

db.transaction(function (tx){
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ProjSetsT (ProjId unique)');
});

for (var i = 0; i < FFFNames.length; i++){
    db.transaction(function (tx){
        tx.executeSql('ALTER TABLE ProjSetsT ADD ? TINYINT(1)', FFFNames[i]);
    });
}
```

Well it did not work. The table got created but no columns added. Is question mark allowed in ALTER or there is something else wrong?

**[Updated on 20th Sep]**: I tried different syntax, like "ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN ? datatype", but it still does not work.

I also tried code like this:

```
db.transaction(function (tx){
    tx.executeSql('ALTER TABLE ProjSetsT ADD COLUMN ? TINYINT(1)', "TEST");
});
```

There is no warning but just does not work.

I also tried:

```
var AAA = "TEST";
db.transaction(function (tx){
    tx.executeSql('ALTER TABLE ProjSetsT ADD COLUMN ? TINYINT(1)', AAA);
});
```

This time I got error:

> *Uncaught Error: TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 17*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html). Also, the second parameter must be an array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < FFFNames.length; i++){
    db.transaction(function (tx){
        tx.executeSql('ALTER TABLE ProjSetsT ADD COLUMN ? TINYINT(1)', [FFFNames[i]]);
    });
}
```

(Update): Apparently, the above query **will not work** because each of the column names will be treated as `'text'`, thereby producing an error. This is what you can do for that query to work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < FFFNames.length; i++){
    db.transaction(function (tx){
        tx.executeSql('ALTER TABLE ProjSetsT ADD COLUMN '+FFFNames[i]+' TINYINT(1)');
    });
}
```

Comment: I'll give a go tomr. But by book it seems we should use ADD (no COLUMN) and DROP COLUMN. Hey...maybe it is product dependent.

Comment: Please see my updates above. It seems this is not the root cause.

Comment: I see the error now - I'm sorry I did not notice the other error the first time. The second parameter must be an array even if there is only one parameter. So make sure you enclose the second parameter with the square bracket.

Comment: You are right. But this does not help too much. The syntax warning goes but it still does not work. I saw explaination from some other place that: one can not use question mark in ALTER clause at all and question mark can only be used for data manipulations. Are you agree with that?

Comment: That makes sense! I agree with you and have updated my answer. :)

Comment: It works if we compose the query as string as you put in your answer. But the "`" is not necessary.

Comment: oops, im sorry. i updated the answer. backticks are for mysql. :)